# Every embedded manifold can be written as a graph of a function

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, submanifold, tangent-spaces

a while ago I was studying about manifolds and this question gave me some troubles:

Let $f:U \to \Bbb{R}$ a $C^{1}$ class function, $U \subset \Bbb{R}^{n}$ an open. Prove the following:

**I:** The graph of $f$ is a differential and orientable manifold in $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$;

**II:** The tangent space of $graph(f)$ is given by $T_{a}M = \{a\}\times \{(u,v) \in \Bbb{R}^{n} \times \Bbb{R}; v = \nabla f(a)u \}$;

**III:** Every embedded manifold can by written (localy) as a graph of a function.

So, any help you could give, I'll be extremely grateful. I think that the idea of the question is to prove **III** with **I** and **II**.

Comment: The answer requires a whole chapter of a differential geometry book! In short, embedding $\Rightarrow$ immersion $\Rightarrow$ locally a graph. The proof is based on the inverse mapping theorem, see for example these [notes](http://idv.sinica.edu.tw/ftliang/diff_geom/*diff_geometry(I)/10.16/submfd.pdf).

Comment: @Chrystomath Thanks for the notes! And about the Tangent Space, do you have some tip?